# Vue.js dosen't render form's elements

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am a newbie in Vue.js. I want to create a multistep registration component.
It will be 2 forms with buttons "Next" and "Previous".

I created a template. Unfortunately, Vue.js doesn't render my form (inputs and buttons). It shows the only div with background and text "Debug"
My other components works, but this one has trouble.

```
<template>
  <div class="l-signup-container">
    <div class="l-signup">
      <v-form v-model="validSignUp">
        <div v-if="step === 1">
          <h1>1 шаг</h1>
          <v-text-field label="Полное Имя"
                        v-model="newUser.name"
                        :rules="rules"
                        required
                        color="light-blue lighten-1">
          </v-text-field>

          <v-text-field label="Название Организации"
                        v-model="newUser.company"
                        :rules="rules"
                        required
                        color="light-blue lighten-1">
          </v-text-field>

          <v-text-field label="Адрес электронной почты"
                        v-model="newUser.email"
                        :rules="rules"
                        required
                        color="light-blue lighten-1">
          </v-text-field>

          <v-text-field label="Пароль"
                        v-model="newUser.password"
                        prepend-icon="lock"
                        :rules="rules"
                        :append-icon="signUpPasswordVisible ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
                        :append-icon-cb="() => (signUpPasswordVisible = !signUpPasswordVisible)"
                        :type="signUpPasswordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'"
                        color="light-blue lighten-1"
                        required>
          </v-text-field>
          <v-btn block color="light-blue lighten-1" @click.prevent="next()">Дальше</v-btn>
        </div>

        <div v-if="step === 2">
          <h1>Пригласить сотрудников</h1>
          <v-text-field label="Адрес электронной почты"
                        v-model="newUser.email"
                        :rules="rules"
                        required
                        color="light-blue lighten-1">
          </v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Адрес электронной почты"
                        v-model="newUser.email"
                        :rules="rules"
                        required
                        color="light-blue lighten-1">
          </v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Адрес электронной почты"
                        v-model="newUser.email"
                        :rules="rules"
                        required
                        color="light-blue lighten-1">
          </v-text-field>

          <v-btn block color="light-blue lighten-1" @click.prevent="prev()">Назад</v-btn>
          <v-btn block color="light-blue lighten-1" @click.native="submitSignUp()">Начать работу</v-btn>

        </div>

      </v-form>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>Debug: {{registration}}
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import TestReg from '@/components/pages/TestReg'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      validSignUp: false,
      signUpPasswordVisible: false,
      rules: [ (value) => !!value || 'This field is required' ],
      newUser: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        company: '',
        password: ''
      },
      message: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    prev () {
      this.step--
    },
    next () {
      this.step++
    },
    submitSignUp () {
      TestReg.signup(this, this.newUser, '/')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "./../../../assets/styles";
  .l-signup {
    background-color: $background-color;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 45px auto;
    min-width: 272px;
    max-width: 320px;
    animation: slideInFromLeft 1s forwards ease;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your console?

Comment: The console didn't show me any errors with this component

Comment: It doesn't look like you've declared `step` is data, I would have expected that to give you an error.

Comment: @DaraShel Where did you register `v-form`, `v-text-field` and `v-btn` components?
And also you don't have `step` and `registration` data but you tried to access them in render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your component. I guess you must define a few variables in you `data` property:

```
data () {
    return {
      validSignUp: false,
      signUpPasswordVisible: false,
      rules: [ (value) => !!value || 'This field is required' ],
      step: 1,
      registration: '',
      //...
    }
}
```